# Where do I put my toastr service in angular?

Tags: angular, toastr

I want have a standard api response like following.

For success response:

```
 {
    "version": "1.0",
    "statusCode": 200,
    "result": {data....}
 }
```

For error response:

```
 {
    "version": "1.0",
    "statusCode": 500, (this may be 401, 404,403,...)
    "errorMessage": {message....}
 }
```

My service like following:

```
export class MyService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`http://localhost/data`).pipe(map((response: any) => {
      return response;
    }))
  }
}
```

I need to show popups if response has errors using toastr. So where I use my toastr service for best solution?

- Component class
- Service class
- Http interceptor

I do not want to repeat myself.

Comment: Component is better

Comment: If you won't show anything other than `errorMessage` (ie something specific to component), the interceptor or a custom HTTP service could be a better place for the sake of not repeating the same code. But if you want to show some component-specific message, then it is better to inject it the components you want.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I updated pust, my error type codes may be 401, 404,403, ....

Comment: I think it is better to create a service for it. The reason is because I usually use Angular Material's Snackbar (https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview) for the same things you want to do. Then, I would use that service in an HTTPWrapper, or interceptor for common messages, and then use it in components for specific messages.

Comment: Then I recommend catching and handling errors in an interceptor by checking the response status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a lot of http requests, You can centralize it by using an  **http interceptor** , try something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(public toasterService: ToastrService) {}

intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        tap(evt => {
            if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
                if(evt.body && evt.body.success)
                    this.toasterService.success(evt.body.success.message, evt.body.success.title, { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-center' });
            }
        }),
        catchError((err: any) => {
            if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                try {
                    this.toasterService.error(err.error.message, err.error.title, { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-center' });
                } catch(e) {
                    this.toasterService.error('An error occurred', '', { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-center' });
                }
                //log error 
            }
            return of(err);
        }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a service like this:

```
declare var toastr;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ToastrService {
  displayToastr(type?: string, message?: string, autoFade?: boolean) {

    var timeOut: any = "5000"

    if (autoFade == false) {
      timeOut = "0"
    }
    toastr.options = {
      "closeButton": true,
      "timeOut": timeOut,
    }

    switch (type) {

      case "success":

        if (message == null) {
          message = "Data Saved Successfully";
        }
        toastr.success(message);

        break;

      case "error":

        if (message == null) {
          message = "Something Went Wrong!";
        }
        toastr.error(message);

        break;

      case "warning":

        if (message == null) {
          message = "Warning!";
        }
        toastr.warning(message);

        break;

      case "clear":

        toastr.clear();

        break;

    }
  }

}
```

and then call it from your component like this:

```
constructor(private toastr: ToastrService){}

this.toastr.displayToastr("success", "User Deleted Successfully")
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it in `constructor`of your component class like this

```
constructor(private toastr: ToastrService){}
```

and then on any event you can call it using

```
this.toastr.success("It works...");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
    //import your service here also 
    import { MyService } from './path/to/my.service'

    @Component({...})
    export class YourComponent {
       constructor(private toastr: ToastrService,private myService:MyService) {}

       getListData() {
       var data = myService.getData();
         if(data.statusCode==500) {
            this.toastr.error(data.errorMessage, 'Major Error');
         }
       }
   }
```

Comment: I can use this way but I have tones of http service requests. So your solution looks like expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a toaster service and Inject that service in your root Interceptor. It will help you to generate HTTP errors on API's behavior (What ever the status code is). As well as if you want custom error toasts on your component level you can use them as well, injecting the service in your components.

Your toaster service will have switch cases base on error codes(400,403,404 etc). In your interceptors just call the service function with the parameter of status code.

**toaster.service.ts**

```
httpToast(errCode){
 switch(errCode){
  case 400:
    // your statements
  break;

  case 404:
  // your statements
  break;
 }
  ..... // cases goes on
}
```